# Awk as an ifconfig filter

Tags: awk, ifconfig

I'm new to the whole awk tool, it's seems really complicated to me.

Sample **ifconfig** output:

```
enp2s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 338  bytes 27536 (26.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 338  bytes 27536 (26.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.x  broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 143296  bytes 172270775 (164.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32786  bytes 6774762 (6.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So far I got a command for ifconfig filter that throws away loopback as well as other unwanted stuff.

`ifconfig | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\n\n"} !/^lo/{print}' | awk '{print $1, $2}' | awk '!/^RX/{print}' | awk '!/^TX/{print}'`

And here's an output:

```
enp2s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>
ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
 
wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>
inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

I researched similar problems, but I want to know how to cut from middle of the line using **awk**

I already tried a line like:
`awk '!/flags=/{print}'`
but it removes whole line that include **flags**

Desired output:

```
enp2s0f1:
ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

wlp3s0:
inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
ifconfig |
awk '
/^[[:alnum:]]+: / { # if we encounter an interface name
   n = $1           # save name in variable n
   p = 1            # set flag p=1
}
# interface does not start with "lo" and protocols are inet or ether
n !~ /^lo/ && /^[[:blank:]]+(inet|ether) / {
   if (p) {         # if flag is set
      print n       # print interface name
      p = 0         # reset flag p=0
   }
   print $1, $2     # print protocol and address
}'
```

Comment: It works really nice but has one minor: gives output for loopback and I want to remove that. Thanks for the answer it already helped me a lot! :D

Comment: I changed ```loopback``` to ```lo``` and it works great thanks for helping! I wish I could understand better awk command line tho... :D

Comment: @anubhava this will print the loopback ip address also and if I am right 127.0.0.1 also has to be removed

Comment: @JoelDeleep yes your right it gave loopback ip and I need to get rid off that

Comment: @spyx33: I have refined awk command with some explanation.

Comment: @spyx33 pipe it to 

awk '!/ 127.0.0.1/'
This will remove the loopback address

Comment: @anubhava Wow! Thanks a lot your awesome that's a big help with **awk**!

Comment: @anubhava that will remove the loopback interface only in linux and it will print he ip address like `
inet 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yup now it runs perfect! Big thanks to you all! :D

Comment: @JoelDeleep No it won't print `inet 127.0.0.1` since interface name is `lo:` and that is excluded. Please run this on OP's sample input.

Comment: @anubhava my bad , i just checked the new edit

Comment: `ifconfig | awk '/^[[:alnum:]]+: / && $1 !~ /^lo/ {print $1}
/^[[:blank:]]+(inet|ether) / {print $1, $2}' | awk '!/ 127.0.0.1/' ` I think this will be more compact , a pipe to your first answer @anubhava

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[[:alnum:]]/ {
    f = ($1 == "lo:" ? 0 : 1)
    if (f) {
        print sep $1
        sep = ORS
    }
}
f && ($1 ~ /^(ether|inet)$/) {
    print $1, $2
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
enp2s0f1:
ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

wlp3s0:
inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this command to be more helpful to filter unwanted stuff from the ifconfig command:

```
/sbin/ifconfig/ eth0 | grep 'inet' | cut -d: -f2 |awk '{print $2}'
```

eth0 - to get eth0 ip details
inet - shows only strings containing inet
cut -d: this will convert all inet containing string into a list
-f2 to access 2nd string/line
awk '{print $2}' to get the desire output where $2- for string index at 2nd position

Answer (score 0):

```
ifconfig | awk '/^lo/,/\n\n/{ e=1 }!e && $1!~/^(RX|TX)$/{ print $1,$1~/:/?"":$2}'
```

- The `/^lo/,/\n\n/` will set `e` to 1 for the loopback part.
- We only print something if `e` equals 0 and

  if the first element does not start with an `R` or `T`.
- Finally, only print `$2` is `$1` does not contain a `:`